# WP_Query by an array or list of post slugs

Tags: php, wordpress

Is this possible, I couldn't find the question asked anywhere on the web.

If you had a list of posts by their slug, example:

```
$postslugs = array("page-one","page-two","page-three");
```

And you wanted to create a single query to find all these specific pages:

```
$args=array(  
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),  
'posts_per_page'=> -1,
'post_type' =>      'customtype',
'post_status' =>    'publish',
'pagename' => $postslugs
);

$my_query = new wp_query( $args );
```

The result should come back with the three pages. This of course would not work the way it's written now. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at the documentation for the [`WP_Query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) class, specifically the [Post & Page Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters) section, you'll see it has a handy parameter called `post_name__in` which takes an array of `post_name` (aka slugs). Also, are you sure you need to use `post__not_in` (and maybe `posts_per_page` since you're defining an array of slugs to get already?

```
$names = array( 'page-one', 'page-two', 'page-three' ); 

$query_args = array(  
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => 'customtype',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'post_name__in'  => $names
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to notice, that there is some issue with old WordPress versions where post_name it is not = to a post_slug.
For example if you try to create new post with title `Customer.io` it will create a post with name `customer-io` but slug will be `customerio` the same will be for this `Pokéapi`
The same will be if you change post slug after you have created the post.
So the best way is to check manually inside loop of your WP_Query.

```
$desired_array_of_slugs = array( 'page-one', 'page-two', 'page-three' ); 

$query_args = array(  
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => 'customtype',
    'post_status'    => 'publish'
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
```

Then

```
foreach($my_query as $post) {
    if(in_array(sanitize_title($post->name)], $desired_array_of_slugs, true)){
        //do ur staff
    }
}
```